# Typescript input onchange event.target.value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

In my react and typescript app, I use:

```
onChange={(e) => data.motto = (e.target as any).value}
```

How do I correctly define the typings for the class, so I wouldn't have to hack my way around the type system with `any`?

```
export interface InputProps extends React.HTMLProps<Input> {
...

}

export class Input extends React.Component<InputProps, {}> {
}
```

If I put `target: { value: string };` I get :

```
ERROR in [default] /react-onsenui.d.ts:87:18
Interface 'InputProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLProps<Input>'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 939, accepted):

Generally event handlers should use `e.currentTarget.value`, e.g.:

```js
const onChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const newValue = e.currentTarget.value;
}
```

You can read why it so here ([Revert "Make SyntheticEvent.target generic, not SyntheticEvent.currentTarget."](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239)).

UPD: As mentioned by @roger-gusmao `ChangeEvent` more suitable for typing form events.

```js
const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const newValue = e.target.value;
}
```

Comment: This simply does not work. value is not a property of the interface EventTarget

Comment: Of course not EventTarget, but part of HTMLInputElement

You can see full definition here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L279

Comment: Oh sorry, you used `currentTarget`. In that case yes, it works, but the question was about `target`

Comment: Yes, you right, but as mentioned in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239 using `target` incorrect in most cases. Moreover, target does not  have `T` to force us to write correctly

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to cast the event to `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` rather than a FormEvent.

Comment: by using ```e.target.value``` ,only ```ChangeEvent``` works

Comment: `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` is a very common TypeScript type that is used for this case in React. You can see a list of other common types on this cheat sheet: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#basic-prop-types-examples

Comment: @AnthonyAvila yeah, right. I do not even remeber why I suggested FormEvent. ChangeEvent is a right version

Comment: `FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>` and `e.currentTarget.value` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 249):

the correct way to use in TypeScript is

```
  handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    // No longer need to cast to any - hooray for react!
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
        ...
        <input value={temperature} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        ...
    );
  }
```

Follow the complete class, it's better to understand:

```
import * as React from "react";

const scaleNames = {
  c: 'Celsius',
  f: 'Fahrenheit'
};


interface TemperatureState {
   temperature: string;
}

interface TemperatureProps {
   scale: string;

}

class TemperatureInput extends React.Component<TemperatureProps, TemperatureState> {
  constructor(props: TemperatureProps) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};
  }

  //  handleChange(e: { target: { value: string; }; }) {
  //    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});  
  //  }


  handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    // No longer need to cast to any - hooray for react!
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

export default TemperatureInput;
```

Comment: note: to ensure types are available, add `lib: ["dom"]` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: And if you have multiple inputs do you need to make a row for each?

Comment: Another way to make sure 'this' is assigned appropriately in the handleChange function would be to write handleChange as an arrow function i.e. handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { this.setState(...); };  By doing that, one would no longer have to use the constructor to bind the handleEvent function.

Comment: One more way to handle 'this' instead of using the constructor and bind method would be to use the arrow function in the onChange prop i.e. onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}

Comment: With these changes I am getting error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): Input', gave the following error.
    Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: CustomEvent<ChangeDetail>) => void'.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I found this worked in later versions of react:

React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>

Answer (score 89):

You can do the following:

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
   const newValue = e.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

`ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` is the type for change event in typescript. This is how it is done-

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 24):

we can also use the onChange event fire-up with defined types(in functional component) like as follows:

```
 const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
};
```

Answer (score 18):

`as HTMLInputElement` works for me

Comment: That doesn't have a `.target`?

Comment: @J86 It's the target you're casting `as HTMLInputElement`. Since the `EventTarget` is an HTML element

Answer (score 14):

I use something like this:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';


export const InputChange = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ value: '' });

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{ value: string }>) => {
    setState({ value: event?.currentTarget?.value });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} />
      <p>{state?.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Finally something worked. I still don't understand how a ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> does not have a value on currentTarger or target...

Answer (score 12):

The `target` you tried to add in `InputProps` is not the same `target` you wanted which is in `React.FormEvent`

So, the solution I could come up with was, extending the event related types to add your target type, as:

```
interface MyEventTarget extends EventTarget {
    value: string
}

interface MyFormEvent<T> extends React.FormEvent<T> {
    target: MyEventTarget
}

interface InputProps extends React.HTMLProps<Input> {
    onChange?: React.EventHandler<MyFormEvent<Input>>;
}
```

Once you have those classes, you can use your input component as

```
<Input onChange={e => alert(e.target.value)} />
```

without compile errors. In fact, you can also use the first two interfaces above for your other components.

Comment: The value type is not string!

Answer (score 11):

When using Child Component We check type like this.

Parent Component:

```
export default () => {

  const onChangeHandler = ((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Input onChange={onChangeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component:

```
type Props = {
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

export Input:React.FC<Props> ({onChange}) => (
  <input type="tex" onChange={onChange} />
)
```

Comment: tiny edit remove extraneous parentheses - const onChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {

Answer (score 10):

An alternative that has not been mentioned yet is to type the onChange function instead of the props that it receives. Using React.ChangeEventHandler:

```
const stateChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 8):

```
const handleChange = (
    e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ ...currentState, [name]: value });
  };
```

you can apply this on every `input` element in the form component

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way with ES6 object destructuring, tested with TS 3.3.
This example is for a text input.

```
name: string = '';

private updateName({ target }: { target: HTMLInputElement }) {
    this.name = target.value;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer that works across the board. I was heavy on Angular, was forced onto React for a year, and am now playing with Angular again to stay fresh on it. React provides some really nice event interfaces that Typescript natively lacks. This approach helps get the same desired typing, even in vanilla. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is when you're working with a `FileList` Object:

```js
onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  const fileListObj: FileList | null = event.target.files;
  if (Object.keys(fileListObj as Object).length > 3) {
    alert('Only three images pleaseeeee :)');
  } else {
    // Do something
  }

  return;
}}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me also it is framework agnostic.

```
const handler = (evt: Event) => {
  console.log((evt.target as HTMLInputElement).value))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You no need to type if you do this:

```
<input onChange={(event) => { setValue(e.target.value) }} />
```

Because if you set a new value with the arrow function directly in the html tag, typescript will understand by default the type of event.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [@haind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2284020/haind)

Yes `HTMLInputElement` worked for input field

```
//Example
var elem = e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
elem.setAttribute('my-attribute','my value');
elem.value='5';
```

This `HTMLInputElement` is interface is inherit from `HTMLElement` which is inherited from `EventTarget` at root level. Therefore we can assert using `as` operator to use specific interfaces according to the context like in this case we are using `HTMLInputElement` for input field other interfaces can be `HTMLButtonElement`, `HTMLImageElement` etc.

[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement]

For more reference you can check other available interface here

- [Web API interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) by Mozilla
- [Interfaces in External Node Modules](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/modules/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.html) by Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

```
const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newValue = (event.target || event.currentTarget) as HTMLInputElement;
    return newValue.value;
}
```

Comment: When we can expect not having `event.target`? I'm interested what case it handles? `event.target || event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 1):

```
  function handle_change(
    evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ): string {
    evt.persist(); // This is needed so you can actually get the currentTarget
    const inputValue = evt.currentTarget.value;

    return inputValue
  }
```

And make sure you have `"lib": ["dom"]` in your `tsconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert string to number simple answer**

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={incrementAmount}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setIncrementAmmount(+e.target.value);
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked great for me.

```
  const [form, setForm] = useState<string>();

  const updateFormState = (event: { target: { value: React.SetStateAction<string | undefined>; }; }) => {
    setForm(event.target.value)
    console.log(form)
  }
```

And then the form in the return

```
<form onSubmit={handleClick}>
        <label>Input</label>
        <input value={form} onChange={updateFormState} type='text'></input>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NativeSyntheticEvent, TextInputChangeEventData,} from 'react-native';



  // Todo in java script
 const onChangeTextPassword = (text : any) => {
    setPassword(text);
  }
```

**//   Todo in type script use this**

```
  const onChangeTextEmail = ({ nativeEvent: { text },}: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>) => {
    console.log("________ onChangeTextEmail _________ "+ text);
    setEmailId(text);
  };


 <TextInput
          style={{ width: '100%', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'grey', height: 40, }}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          returnKeyType="next"
          maxLength={50}
          secureTextEntry={false}
          onChange={onChangeTextEmail}
          value={emailId}
          defaultValue={emailId}
          
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const event = { target: { value: 'testing' } as HTMLInputElement };
handleChangeFunc(event as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>);
```

this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone having trouble with event.target.file, you can refer to the following code which solved my problem for my react project.

```
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const selectedFile: File = (target.files as FileList)[0];
    console.log("Selected File:", selectedFile, event);
  };
```