# Can't pass a head of a method to event handling in React markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, event-handling

In my *render()* I have the following component with event handling.

```
render() { ...
  <input type="text" 
         onChange={(_) => { this.restate("email", _.target.value); }} />
}

private restate(type: string, input: any) { ...
  if (type === "email")
    this.setState({ ... });
}
```

This works and behaves as supposed to. Since I'm learning React right now, I try to improve my syntax so it's smooth on the eyes. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820103/1525840) and liked the brevity of the event handler assignment. So I've changed my rendering and implemented the handler to be passed as follows.

```
render() { ...
  <input type="text" onChange={ this.handleEmail } />
}

private handleEmail(data: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  console.log("hit before: " + data.target.value);
  console.log(this);
  this.restate("email", data.target.value);
}
```

The change in the markup seems to work, because the method *handleEmail(...)* is invoked. However, I get an error saying that *restate(...)* is not a method of *undefined* and, in fact, when I investigate what *this* is, I discovered it's *undefined*.

I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong and how it deviates from the article linked to above. I tried to google for the syntax differences between versions of React but got nothing. And I'm not sure how to describe the issue in correct technical terms.

Comment: Did you bind your function in `constructor()` ?

Comment: [binding patterns](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Instead of binding it you can <input type="text" onChange={ (e) => this.handleEmail(e) } />

Comment: @kiranvj No, I did not. Now, that you say so, I see that part implemented in the constructor of the provided example. It seems to work so you might want to repost your comment as a reply so it can be accepted. Still, the syntax *this.foo=this.foo.bind(this)* looks retarded. If *this* is there, then it should be there without putting it there. I guess it's my ignorance of React that shines through here...

Comment: @LazarNikolic Would you mind reposting your comment as a reply and fill in a row or two discussing pros and cons of the different bind/-not-bind approaches? It might be useful for the future generations (starting with me).

Comment: I wrote it as an answer. Hope it is clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you should do is

```
render() { ...
  <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleEmail(e) } />
}
```

I think the reason why your restate method was not a method of `undefined` is because your method was not binded to the component. In order for your methods to be a part of react class you need to bind that method to the class. There are couple of ways to do that. In class constructor like this:

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
 }
```

or inside render function, like I showed above. Third is to use arrow function inside class body like this:

```
handleEmail = () => {
  // call this function from render 
  // and this.whatever in here works fine.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `this` inside your onClick function you need to bind it inside the constructor. You can also use bind in `render()` also, but this is not recommended as `bind` will be called multiple times. The react docs recommends to use `bind` inside constructor like this

```
constructor() {
  super(); 
  this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
}
```

This is not something specific to React, its JavaScript. Its by design.

This is what [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) does

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**Question**

Why does you first example worked?

```
render() { ...
  <input type="text" 
         onChange={(_) => { this.restate("email", _.target.value); }} />
}
```

This is because you used the ES6 arrow function `()=> {}`. This is also called fat arrow functions.

Whenever you use arrow function, `this` is captured from the surrounded context and you can use `this` inside your function without binding. That why your first example worked.

Your second example would have worked if you have used like this

```
render() { ...
  <input type="text" onChange={ ()=> this.handleEmail() } />
}
```

I would suggest to read this excellent [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb) for more details on `bind`