# React TypeScript: Correct Types for onChange

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What are the correct types for `target: { value: any, name: any }`? The error I get is `Duplicate identifier 'any'.` I also get the error `Binding element 'any' implicitly has an 'any' type.` And why does `value` give the error 'Cannot find name 'value'?'

I have a [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-mountain-6qri4)

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    fullName: '',
});

const { fullName } = state;

const onChange = ({ target: { value: any, name: any } }) => {
    setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name] : value, // <= 'Cannot find name 'value'
    }));
};

...

<input
  type='text'
  placeholder='Full name'
  name='fullName'
  value={fullName}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Comment: **See Also**: [Typescript input onchange event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40676343/1366033)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`event` from `onChange` should be `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

So, you must do this:

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');

...

const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFullName(event.currentTarget.value);
};

...

<input
  type='text'
  placeholder='Full name'
  name='fullName'
  value={fullName}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Comment: And Should I import ChangeEvent like `import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';`

Comment: When I come to type into the inputs I can type 1 character then I can't enter any more

Comment: @Bill yes, you should import ChangeEvent from "react";

Comment: @Bill can you publish example of your code at any sandbox?

Comment: @Bill check it https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-field-om8d3
You must call .persist of your event because https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: how about using useCallback for onChange

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko can you clarify your question? You can use useCallback hook if you wont and if you need.