# React Typescript input onChange event type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, input

I'm trying to get text from a input element, setting it to state and then rendering it back into the input box. However I think my event typing is wrong? I've searched online and tried implementing many solutions but none have worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

my component:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, ChangeEventHandler, useState } from "react";

export default function Unidirectionflow() {
  const [state4, setState4] = useState("");
  const [state5, setState5] = useState("");

  let handleChange4 = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setState3((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  };

  let handleChange5 = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState5(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <input type="text" value={state4} onChange={() => handleChange4} />
      <input type="text" value={state5} onChange={() => handleChange5} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

[Typescript input onchange event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value)

[React TypeScript: Correct Types for onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137232/react-typescript-correct-types-for-onchange)

[Can't type in React TextField Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092720/cant-type-in-react-textfield-input)

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have forgot to pass the `event` when calling the function

Try this

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

Or

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-pateu-1mc6j?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Sujio, check this out!!

Comment: No reference to Typescript as requested in the question

Answer (score 4):

**You can do like this**

```
export default function Unidirectionflow() {
const [states, setStates] = useState({
state3:'',
state4:''
})

const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setStates({
      ...states,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <input type="text" name="state3" value={states.state3} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input type="text" name="state4" value={states.state4} onChange={handleChange} />
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
handleChange = (event: Event) => {
      const { value } = event.target as unknown as { value: string };
      setState(value);
};
  
<input type='text' onChange={handleChange} />
```

And the squeegee lines will go away.

Answer (score 0):

onChange={handleChange}
See if this can help you!

Comment: Consider formating code in your answer. Also, add some context to better explain your approach.

Comment: The question asks for Typescript, which is not mentioned in the answer.