# Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, tsx

I'm trying to implement this in a React TypeScript File:

```
export class MainInfo extends Component<IProps>{
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values1, handleChange } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          validateOnChange={true}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          initialValues={{ Title: '', ActivationDate: '', ExpirationDate: '', DirectManager: '', HRBP: '' }}
          onSubmit={(data) => {
            console.log(data)
          }}
```

But I receive a Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type React TypeScript error. How should I fix this?

Edit: I have these in another file that Im using them here as props

```
nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  // Go back to prev step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  // Handle fields change
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: Are you getting a warning or an error?
I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type) would be helpful

Comment: you have to specify a parameter type for `e` in `continue = e => ...` Please advise — what prop is `continue` being passed to?

Comment: @GalAbra its an arror

Comment: `(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>`, something like that should probably fix it.

Answer (score 15):

When writing TypeScript you should refer to the source code or docs of the library to know what its types are

For example, in Formik's [`types.tsx`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/packages/formik/src/types.tsx#L130), we see

```
handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void;
```

We can also look in React's [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1207) to see:

```
interface ChangeEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T>
```

So, something like

```
handleChange = input => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
};
```

...might work for you.

Also if your IDE supports TypeScript that will help.

Answer (score 6):

It is interesting to note that you will not see this error if you are writing inline event handlers, but then why do you see it in this context?

The reason you are seeing that error message is because of the type inference system in TypeScript and how it works.

TypeScript is always trying to figure out the different types of values flowing around your application and that's what the type inference system does.

Let me demonstrate with a screenshot. In the screenshot below I have moused over `onChange` and you will notice that TypeScript is 100% aware of what that `onChange` prop really is, it understands it's a prop, it understands I am required to provide some kind of callback function to it. It says that if I decided to provide that function to `onChange`, it will have a first argument called `event` and its type will be `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`:

[image]

If I mouse over `e` inline, notice I get the exact same type:

[image]

However, the type inference system is not applied if I define the function ahead of time. Even if I define the function ahead of time and pass it down into the `onChange` prop, type inference will not be applied.

Type inference is only defined inside the JSX when we define the callback function directly inline.

So how do you fix this? How do we define `onChange` in my example ahead of time and still annotate the type of my event object?

Well, I can mouse over `onChange` as you saw in the above screenshot and highlight and copy the type of event which is `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` and put a colon after `event` and paste that type in.

In my example it would be:

```
const EventComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event);
  };

   return (
     <div>
       <input onChange={onChange} />
     </div>
   );
};
```

Which means, to solve your problem, it would look like so:

```
export class MainInfo extends Component<IProps>{
  continue = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
```

Notice the event type says `ChangeEvent`? Just be aware that there are other events inside of React code such as hover or drag that you might want to annotate as well. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 5):

You have to give `e` a type. For example:

```
continue = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Typescript will scream at you if you don't assign types to variables and function arguments.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ex-5ev2f could you please look at this tsx file and tell what type e is based on the props in the question? I dont know what to assign to it

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle a form submission using `onSubmit` handler, give `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` type to `e`:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        { props.children }
      </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw the same problem myself when trying to add an event handler for the onChange event.

```
function handleChange(event) {
    var _userDetails = userDetails;
    _userDetails[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setUserDetails({ ..._userDetails });
};
```

event.target.name was showing the error that event implicitly had an 'any' type.

Adding a type to the event did'nt work and then noticed I had named my file with a .tsx extension and not.jsx

Changing the type to jsx solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you just need to set the type of event to FormEvent and import it from the react.

```
import { FormEvent } from "react";

    const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case e is an Event of some kind. If you don't know what Type something is 'any' is the default e.g.

```
handleChange = input => (e:any) => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };
```

So in the short term use any. If you want to know exactly what type it is it likely an Input Event and you might find this [Typescript input onchange event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value/42645711) useful

Comment: When I work if I don't know what Type it is I will set it to 'any' until I am in a position to actually know what the type is - as I say above in the 'short term'