# TypeScript error using Function as React prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a checkbox React TypeScript component. I need to accept an `onChange` function, but all that I know is that it will be a function.

I thought I could use the generic function type:

```
type Props = {
  onChange: Function;
};
```

However when I try and use it I get an error:

```
// From Material UI
<CheckboxComponent onChange={onChange}>
```

> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent, checked: boolean) => void'.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value

Comment: Have you considered using the more specific type? Not all `Function`s are `(event: ChangeEvent, checked: boolean) => void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste the type from the error into the props type:

```
type Props = {
  onChange: (event: ChangeEvent, checked: boolean) => void;
};
```

Then adjust your function to that type.

Comment: there is already a type for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value