# React (events) Typescript type definition for event.target.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my click event for React I have specified a type for the event, but for some reason it says

> type value is not on the event type

Code so far is:

```
type ButtonEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>;

<Button variant="primary" onClick={(event: ButtonEvent): void => alert(event.target.value)}>Primary</Button>
```

I can't seem to use `event.target.value`, any idea's why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript input onchange event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value)

Answer (score 0):

you should add property `value` to your `Button`  :

```
<Button value="what you want" variant="primary" onClick={(event: ButtonEvent): void => alert(event.target.value)}>Primary</Button>
```