# typescript onChange event type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, react-typescript

how can I specify the event type for radio buttons with ReactJs and typescript

I tried this but it doesn't works for radio buttons though it works for input type="text"

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   ....    
};
```

```
<FormControlLabel
 value="radio1"
 control={<Radio />}
 label=" radio1"
 onChange={handleChange}
/>
<FormControlLabel
 value="radio2"
 control={<Radio />}
 label="radio2"
 onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

**Error**

```
Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<{}>, checked: boolean) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 329 more.ts(2322)
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42645711/547020) implies that `React.FormEvent` should be used (instead of `React.ChangeEvent`)

Comment: this isn't working either

Comment: after reading more, it looks like  `currentTarget` is preferred over `target` in most implementations. it's meant to deal with state updates, but here's the interesting part: it seems that a text input is the only element that can accept `target` with no special issues - which is probably related to the issues you're having on the typescript build - it has a separate interface altogether. i would look into what differs this interface from other form controls, i'm sure you'll find some hints there on how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,
Any way I found the solution.
`<HTMLInputElement>` is not assignable to radio buttons, so we can do the following to skip the built error,

```
(event: React.ChangeEvent<Record<string, unknown>>) {
console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

The above code should be used if we have radio button groups.

Otherwise, for a single radio button, this should be used

```
(event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, checked: boolean) {
  console.log(checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // use event.currentTarget.value here
}
```